# How can I add a REST request in my middleware to validate credentials on a another service?

Tags: node.js, express

I have an Nodejs Express app and I wrote middleware to validate credentials against hardcoded values and it works perfectly. I want to add a REST request to another service to validate passed credentials. I thought this would be straighforward by adding a promise to my call, unfortunately computer says no and I don't know how to proceed.

**Working middleware**

```
var allowAccess = function (req, res, next) {
  logAcces();
  config.errorMessage = '';
  if(!config.allowAccess){
    let userAdmin = {};
    userAdmin.username = req.body.username || false;
    userAdmin.password = req.body.password || false;
    if(userAdmin.username != false && userAdmin.password != false){
      if(userAdmin.username !=  config.validUser.username || userAdmin.password !=  config.validUser.password){
        res.status(401).json({ login: 'false' });
        return;
      } else {
        config.allowAccess = true;
        res.json({ login: 'true' });
        return;
      }
    } else {
      config.errorMessage = '';
      dispatchResponse('body-login', res, null, null);
      return;
    }
  }
  next();
}
app.use(allowAccess);
```

The approach I used below is similar to my other endpoints that do *block* while I fetch data from the same service to build my response but it doesn't behave as I expected in the middleware. Instead it reports

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

and when I try to set debug points it doesn't stop. It just carries on to `res.status(401).json({ login: 'false' });` and my front end ajax call handles the response.

**Middleware with added promise**

```
var allowAccess = function (req, res, next) {
  logAcces();
  config.errorMessage = '';
  if(!config.allowAccess){
    let userAdmin = {};
    userAdmin.username = req.body.username || false;
    userAdmin.password = req.body.password || false;
    if(userAdmin.username != false && userAdmin.password != false){

      async function checkAdminStatus() {
        try {
          var test = getAuthToken(userAdmin);
          await rp(test).then(function (response) {

          /*
            This is where I would check if the user is valid, I left the original condition alone for this post as I don't get here anyway
           */
          let isAdmin = response;
          if(userAdmin.username !=  config.validUser.username || userAdmin.password !=  config.validUser.password){
            res.status(401).json({ login: 'false' });
            return;
          } else {
            config.allowAccess = true;
            res.json({ login: 'true' });
            return;
          }

          }).catch(function (err) {
            config.errorMessage = 'Authentication Failed: Bad credentials';
            dispatchResponse('body-error', res, null, 'Error, please try again');
          });
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("Error: ", error);
        }
      }
      checkAdminStatus();

    } else {
      config.errorMessage = '';
      dispatchResponse('body-login', res, null, null);
      return;
    }
  }
  next();
}
app.use(allowAccess);
```

Could someone please show me where I'm going wrong, without debug* I can't figure this out?

*debug: I can set debug points any where else in my code and it stops except in the REST call on my middle ware.

**UPDATE**
I'm adding this here for future users. It is fully working middleware that validates passed login credentials against a service.
The `getAuthToken(userAdmin)` call builds the parameter string for the request.

```
var allowAccess = function (req, res, next) {
  if(!config.allowAccess){
    let userAdmin = {};
    userAdmin.username = req.body.username || false;
    userAdmin.password = req.body.password || false;
    if(userAdmin.username != false && userAdmin.password != false){

      async function checkUser() {
        try {
          await rp(getAuthToken(userAdmin)).then(function (response) {

            config.token = response.body.authToken;
            if(response.body.roles.includes("Admin")) {
              config.allowAccess = true;
              res.json({ login: 'true' });
              return;
            } else {
              res.status(401).json({ login: 'false' });
              return;
            }
          }).catch(function (err) {
            res.status(401).json({ login: 'false' });
            return;
          });
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("Error: ", error);
        }
      }
      checkUser();

    } else {
      config.errorMessage = '';
      dispatchResponse('body-login', res, null, null);
      return;
    }
  } else {
    next();
  }
}
app.use(allowAccess);
```

Comment: I'm not sure why I got a downvote with the detail I gave. Without a comment as to why you do not allow me make amends and fix the issue so I learn nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is the way you are using an async function

When you call `checkAdminStatus` it will go to the event loop queue, and before its completion `next()` function executed so it will go to next middleware in the stack, and from that middleware, you are sending the response.

Once the call stack gets empty your `checkAdminStatus` will be executed and inside this function, you are again trying to send the response that's why you are getting the error `ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT`

In order to fix this what you need to do is wrap the next() call to else

```
if(!config.allowAccess){
  ...
}
else {
  next()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your explantion on the event loop queue and stack made perfect sense. I could have read dozens of docs and not spotted that. :P

Comment: Glad! that it helps you

Answer (score 0):

your code needs to be clear, 
first, let's refactor your code
you must split your functions and don't merge between async-await and then chine, 
also don't use both of them to the same function .
your have many issues but your main issue is you need to add a `await` before calling this function `checkAdminStatus` or just return it 
`await checkAdminStatus()`

```
const allowAccess = async function(req, res, next) {
  logAcces();
  config.errorMessage = '';
  if (!config.allowAccess) {
    let userAdmin = {};
    userAdmin.username = req.body.username || false;
    userAdmin.password = req.body.password || false;
    const checkAuth=userAdmin.username !== false && userAdmin.password !== false
    if (checkAuth) {
      return checkAdminStatus(userAdmin, config, res);
    } else {
      config.errorMessage = '';
     return dispatchResponse('body-login', res, null, null);
    }
  }
  next();
}
async function checkAdminStatus(userAdmin, res) {
  try {
    var test = getAuthToken(userAdmin);
    const response = await rp(test)
    let isAdmin = response;
    const checkAuth=userAdmin.username !== config.validUser.username || userAdmin.password !== config.validUser.password
    if (checkAuth) return res.status(401).json({ login: 'false' });
    config.allowAccess = true;
    return res.json({ login: 'true' });
  } catch (error) {
    config.errorMessage = 'Authentication Failed: Bad credentials';
    return dispatchResponse('body-error', res, null, 'Error, please try again');
  }
}

app.use(allowAccess);
```

Comment: If you are the one that downvoted I now see what you mean with the above answer.